# Accessing PHP file on localhost (my computer) from my phone

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data entered by client to server running at my computer. For that i am using ajax call with ip address of server but it is not working.

post.php is stored at server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {

    $('#waiting').show(500);
    $('#demoForm').hide(0);
    $('#message').hide(0);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://172.21.6.197/kalimba/post.php',
        dataType : 'json',

        data: {
            email : $('#email').val()
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .text(data.msg).show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#demoForm').show(500);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .text('There was an error.').show(500);
            $('#demoForm').show(500);
        }
    });

    return false;
  });
 });
```

Comment: Can you manually check if the location is serving or not. Type the address in your mobile browser and check if page is served. What errors did you get ?

Comment: page is serving well on mobile browser but problem is occurring when i use ip address of server instead of localhost

Comment: Just enter only the ip address in your browser and see what error throws up. Did you get a '403 Forbidden'

Comment: Yes,because it is root directory of xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending Ajax requests to other domains, you have to send a CORS header from the receiving server:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```